How to properly add a fluid in CoolProp library?
I'm making a website to calculate heat exchanger solutions. In order to do so, I must calculate complex data, which is why I use the CoolProp library. While the website is handled in PHP, the library is in Python, so I just send my PHP form data to Python, and it returns me the result. This works well.
But the customer needs me to use some fluids which are not in the library: MPG and MEG (on this website it shows a way to use it, but I get an error saying the fluid doesn't exist). Those fluids will even be mixed with water at different percentae (10, 20, 30, 40, and 50%). I've been reading the documentation, mainly this part, but I get some other errors, like :
Unable to validate cubics library against schema with error: {
    "enum": {
        "instanceRef": "#/0/pc_units",
        "schemaRef": "#/items/properties/pc_units"
    }
}

Here is my Python code, and the JSON I'm trying to add:

import sys
import json
import os
import CoolProp.CoolProp as CP


def add_custom_fluids(json_filename):
    with open(json_filename, 'r') as f:
        fluids_json = f.read()


    fluids_data = json.loads(fluids_json)



    # Add each fluid to CoolProp
    for fluid in fluids_data:
        CP.add_fluids_as_JSON('PR', json.dumps(fluid))


    # Verify by printing the fluid list
    fluid_list = CP.get_global_param_string('FluidsList')
    print(fluid_list)



def main():
    try:
        # Ajout des fluides "customs" (MEG-10%, MPG-40%, etc.)
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
        json_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'custom_fluids.json')
        add_custom_fluids(json_file_path)
    
         
        # Récupérer les arguments de la ligne de commande
        output = sys.argv[1]
        input1 = sys.argv[2]
        value1 = float(sys.argv[3])
        input2 = sys.argv[4]
        value2 = float(sys.argv[5])
        fluid = sys.argv[6]


        # Calculate the property using CoolProp
        result = CP.PropsSI(output, input1, value1, input2, value2, fluid)


        # Print the result
        print(result)



    except Exception as e:
        # Print the error message
        print(f"Error: {e}", file=sys.stderr)
        print(0)  # Return 0 in case of error


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


[
    [
        {
            "name": "MPG",
            "description": "Pure Mono Propylene Glycol",
            "incompressible": true,
            "T_min": 183.15,
            "T_max": 590.15,
            "isothermal_compressibility": 4.4e-10,
            ...
            "molemass": 0.06207,
            "molemass_units": "kg/mol",
            "pc_units": "mPa",
            "Tc_units": "K"
        }
    ]
]

After that, I should be able to make a mixture of Water and the new fluids for the different percentages I need.
I tried using the add_fluids_as_JSON() function by looping inside my JSON array, expecting each fluids to be added to the library. I also tried to insert them differently, one entry for each percentage. All of these resulted in the same error.
Edit and "solution" : since I couldn't figure it out, I imported the module called "pyfluids", and for some reason, this one has the fluids I needed. I used it that way :
from pyfluids import Fluid, FluidsList, Input
import json
import sys

# Arguments PHP
pressure = float(sys.argv[1])
temp = float(sys.argv[2])
fluid = sys.argv[3]


# Récupération des données selon le fluide renseigné
if fluid != "Water" :
    fluidArray = fluid.split('-')
    name = fluidArray[0]
    percentage = int(fluidArray[1])
    data = Fluid(getattr(FluidsList, name), percentage).with_state(Input.pressure(pressure), Input.temperature(temp))
else :
    data = Fluid(FluidsList.Water).with_state(Input.pressure(pressure), Input.temperature(temp))

result = {
    'density': data.density,
    'specific_heat': data.specific_heat,
    'dynamic_viscosity': data.dynamic_viscosity,
    'conductivity': data.conductivity,
    'prandtl': data.prandtl
}

print(json.dumps(result))

And it's even better since it calculates all the datas I need in one go, instead of the regular CoolProp that will do one calculation per data you need.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
